# How to run other methods rather than runApp in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

here in the main function first i want to get data from storage and check them so i can block some routes if the user is not logged in

im using JWT and some AuthData to check whether the token is expired or not at the time of app running

```
void main() => {
var authData = await TokenStorageService.authDataOrEmpty;
       runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          title: 'routes',
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFF1F1F1),
          ),
          initialRoute: '/', // Start the app with the "/" named route.
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => HomePage(),
// build the HomePage widget.
            WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),

            Profile.id: (context) => Profile(),
//build welcome screen
            LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
// build the Login widget.
            RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
// build the Register widget.
            '/userLeave': (context) => UserLeave(),
//  build the UserLeave widget.
            '/leaveRequest': (context) => LeaveRequest(),
//  build the LeaveRequest widget.
            '/ownLeave': (context) => OwnLeave(),
//  build the LeaveRequest widget.
            '/allLeaves': (context) => AllLeave(),
//  build the LeaveRequest widget.
          },
        ),
      )
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

u can mark `main` method as async and u r good to go

```
Future<void> main() async {
  var authData = await TokenStorageService.authDataOrEmpty;
  // your other code
}
```

Comment: I figured it out , im now using code inside future builder